# Find Objects that have not a label in any version

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I want to find objects that have not got a LABEL in any version.

I can check if any object has a LABEL in its LATEST version with following command :

```
cleartool find .  -version "version(/main/LATEST) && !lbtype(MYLABEL)" -print
```

And this command also lists all versions :

```
cleartool find .  -version "!lbtype(MYLABEL)" -print
```

I want the object list that has **not got** label (MYLABEL) in any versions. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first try looking for elements instead (with the `lbtype_sub` query primitive):

```
cleartool find .  -ele "!lbtype_sub(MYLABEL)" -print
```

See "[Additional examples of the cleartool find command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)"

#### About `*_sub` query primitives

> When using the ClearCase find command in what circumstances should the *_sub query primitives (attype_sub, label_sub and attr_sub) be used instead of just lbtype or attype?
>
> When the type being queried does not apply to the "level" (`-element -branch -version`) being queried.
> For example, query for a label using `-element`: labels are only on versions within elements

(you can limit to files only with `-type f`, or folders only with with `-type -d`)

---

If that does not work would recommend a three steps process.

- find all the elements (file or folder) that have one version with that label
- find all the elements
- remove the first elements from the second list

The end result is what you are looking for.